# Hibernate Reactive - Spring Boot - Without persistence.xml - DataSource Error

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, datasource, reactive

I want to implement a reactive application. I need to access my database in a reactive way. One way to do that is to use Hibernate Reactive. It’s based on Vert.X and implements the well-known concepts of JPA and Hibernate ORM based on the reactive programming paradigm.

I have this error:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.hibernate.reactive:hibernate-reactive-core:1.1.1.Final")
    implementation("io.vertx:vertx-pg-client:4.2.3")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

```
    private fun hibernateJpaProperties(): Map<String, *> {
        val properties = HashMap<String, String>()
        properties["hibernate.jdbc.time_zone"] = "UTC"
        properties["hibernate.connection.pool_size"] = "10"
        properties["hibernate.show_sql"] = "true"
        properties["hibernate.format_sql"] = "true"
        properties["hibernate.highlight_sql"] = "true"
        properties["javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"] = "drop-and-create"
        return properties
    }

    @Bean
    fun entityManagerFactory(dataSource: DataSource?): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean? {
        val entityManagerFactory = LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.hibernate.reactive.provider.ReactivePersistenceProvider::class.java)
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.xxxx.xxxx.entities");
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("hibernate-persistence");
        if (dataSource != null) {
            entityManagerFactory.dataSource = dataSource
        }
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateJpaProperties())
        return entityManagerFactory
    }

    @Bean
    fun dataSource(): DataSource {
        val dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create()
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test")
        dataSourceBuilder.username("xxxx")
        dataSourceBuilder.password("xxxx")
        return dataSourceBuilder.build()
    }
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/xxxx/xxxx/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxApplicationKt.main(xxxxApplication.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/xxxx/xxxx/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:491) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperty.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:460) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperties.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:355) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.config.PersistenceConfig.dataSource(PersistenceConfig.kt:55) ~[main/:na]
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ef6e2ee.CGLIB$dataSource$1(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ef6e2ee$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$34d52a48.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ef6e2ee.dataSource(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Why this error? I try to use "vertx-pg-client" and "Hibernate Reactive in Spring Boot" without persistece.xml

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you find a way to make it work in the end ? Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

I define spring configuration like this

persistence.xml - define entity and options without dataSource info.

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <provider>org.hibernate.reactive.provider.ReactivePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>com.hpcnt.workshop.hibernate.reactive.model.Author</class>
        <class>com.hpcnt.workshop.hibernate.reactive.model.Book</class>

        <properties>

            <!-- The Vert.x SQL Client connection pool size -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="10"/>

            <!-- Automatic schema export -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>

            <!-- SQL statement logging -->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.highlight_sql" value="true"/>

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

and Define Spring Configuration class with hibernate properties include dataSource settings.

```
@Configuration
class HibernateReactiveConfiguration {

    companion object: KLogging() {
        // MySQL with TestContainers for Testing
        private val mysql = MySQLServer(useDefaultPort = true).apply { start() }
    }

    @Bean
    fun entityManagerFactory(provider: PersistenceProvider): EntityManagerFactory {
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default", hibernateJpaProperties())
    }

    private fun hibernateJpaProperties(): Map<String, Any?> {
        val props = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()

        props["javax.persistence.jdbc.url"] = mysql.jdbcUrl
        props["javax.persistence.jdbc.user"] = mysql.username
        props["javax.persistence.jdbc.password"] = mysql.password
        props["javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"] = "drop-and-create"

        props["hibernate.highlight_sql"] = true

        return props
    }
}
```

It's work!